# Eye contact via the moon

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, reflection, thermal-radiation

Consider two lovers $L_1, L_2$ in different cities looking - as lovers do - at the moon at night.

They do not have line of sight with each other, but maybe they can take comfort in the fact, that they still can technically make "eye contact".

There are photons leaving $L_1$'s eyes due to black-body radiation, biochemical reactions and reflection of surrounding light sources at a rate of $r_0$.

Suppose some of these photons are able to leave earths atmosphere, hit the surface of the moon and be reflected off of it. These photons could travel back through earths atmosphere and hit $L_2$'s eyes at a rate of $r_♥$.

**Question: What are (good approximations for) $r_0$ and $r_♥$?**

---

My naive approach: No atmosphere, perfect reflection, ignoring spherical shape of the moon

$r_m = 1.7374 \cdot 10^6m$ Radius of the moon

$r_e = 1.2 \cdot 10^{-2}m$  Radius of a lovers eye

$d = 3.8440 \cdot 10^8m$ Distance from the earth to the moon

$r_0 = 10^{19}\frac{1}{s}$ Rate of photons given off by $L_1$'s eyes

---

The photons emitted by $L_1$'s eyes will spread out in a sphere. By the time the photons can hit the moon this sphere will have a radius of $d$ and a surface area of $A=4\pi d^2$. We'll approximate the surface area of the moon, that is visible from $L_1$'s position and able to reflect photons back to $L_2$ by a disc with radius $r_m$. This disc has a surface area of $A_m = \pi r_m^2$.

Only a fraction $f_1$ of the photons will hit this disc: $f_1 = \frac{A_m}{A}$

As an approximation we'll say these photons act as if emitted by a point-source and spread out in a sphere. The rate of these photons is $r_1 = f_1 \cdot r_0$

These photons will again spread out in a sphere and by the time they reach $L_2$'s eyes, this sphere will have an Area of $A$. The visible area of $L_2$'s eyes will be (using the same approximation as for the reflecting surface of the moon) $A_e=2\cdot \pi r_e^2$. (factor of two assuming $L_2$ has two eyes)

Only a fraction $f_2$ of the photons will hit this disc: $f_2 = \frac{A_e}{A}$

The rate $r_♥$ of photons hitting $L_2$'s eyes is
$$r_♥=f_2\cdot r_1 = f_1\cdot f_2\cdot r_0=$$
$$\frac{A_m}{A}\cdot\frac{A_e}{A}\cdot r_0= \frac{A_m\cdot A_e}{A^2}r_0=$$
$$\frac{2 \pi^2 r_m^2 r_e^2}{(4 \pi d^2)^2}r_0= \frac{r_m^2r_e^2}{8d^4}r_0=$$
$$\frac{(1.7374 \cdot 10^6m)^2 (1.2 \cdot 10^{-2}m)^2}{8 \cdot (3.8440 \cdot 10^8m)^4} 10^{19}\frac{1}{s}\approx $$
$$2.4885\cdot 10^{-8} \frac{1}{s}$$

Or about $0.8$ photons per year of continuous staring at the moon. Oh no.

This gets even worse, if the moon doesn't perfectly reflect photons (which it doesn't) and if the atmosphere of the earth absorbs some of the photons (which it does). My rate of $r_0$ is also probably a over-estimation. I remembered that a lightbulb gives off around $5\cdot 10^{20}$ photons per second (depending on the lightbulb of course) and just took $2\%$ of that. My hope is that the disc-approximation of the reflection off of the moon is a huge underestimate.

Can someone come to the rescue of $L_1$ and $L_2$?

Comment: This line of reasoning has applications in sonar. Google Sonar Equation, or see https://dosits.org/science/advanced-topics/sonar-equation/